# Asymptotic Notations-Big Oh Notation

Tags: asymptotic-complexity

What is the clear interpretation of this?

```
    O(1)+O(2)+O(3)+O(4)+O(5).......O(n)
```

And how different is this from

```
     sigma O(i) 1<=i<=n?
```

CLRS says it is different but does not explain how are these different?

Comment: What is CLRS? Please explain

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Algorithms-Thomas-H-Cormen/dp/0262033844

Answer (score 0):

If I remember correctly, the asymptotic complexity is always expressed with the highest order function, so

```
O(1)+O(2)+...+O(n)
```

is just

```
O(n)
```

Which makes sense if n is reasonably large. If n is small the whole complexity stuff makes little sense anyway.